# How do I highlight text linked to from a separate webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, highlight

I have a web-page with anchor tags that are linked to specific words in another page that contain only the words.

Every single word in the **words page** is wrapped with an `<a>` anchor tag having a unique ID like this:

```
<a id="a">Капитанская</a>
<a id="b">дочкаБереги</a>
<a id="c">Капитанская</a>
<a id="d">дочкаБереги</a>
```

And in the **web-page** there are links to those words that look like this:

```
<a href="website.com/text-page.html#a">Капитанская</a>
<a href="website.com/text-page.html#b">дочкаБереги</a>
```

---

I need to find a way to highlight the word I'm linking to with a colored background or something like that.

I'm using JavaScript, HTML, CSS and PHP for both the webpages, and don't have the ability to use anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your text page, you can just retrieve the `id` from your url using the `hash` property from the [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) read-only property and assign a background color to the text element that has that id like this:

```js
//get the id from the URL
const link = window.location.hash.split('#')[1];

//add a class to the element that has that id
document.getElementById(link).classList.add('highlighted');
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: green; //add background color to that element
}
```

```html
<a id="word1">word1</a>
<a id="word2">word2</a>
<a id="word3">word3</a>
<a id="word4">word4</a>
<a id="word5">word5</a>
<a id="word6">word6</a>
<a id="word7">word7</a>
<a id="word8">word8</a>
```

Comment: any way this could be done with <a> tag ID's? the text html looks more like this: <a id="0"></a>Капитанская <a id="1"></a>дочкаБереги <a id="2"></a>честь

Comment: @To.byTe.array Yes it works with any element that has the targetted id.

Comment: Can you add the full content of both your html files to a code sandbox like codebin or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You could use css

```
#wordid:target {
    background-color: #ddd;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}
```